# Can we make the following claim?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-differential-equations

Let $\psi = \psi(x,y)$ be a smooth scalar function in $[0,2\pi] \times [0,2\pi]$.

Can we make the claim: $\frac{\nabla^2 \psi}{|\nabla \psi|^2} = f (\psi)$?

Where $f$ is a scalar function. $\nabla$ is the gradient operator and $|\nabla \psi|$ is the Euclidean norm of $\nabla \psi$. $|\nabla \psi|$ is a smooth and positive function. $\nabla^2 \psi$ is the "Surface-Laplacian Operator" or simply the Laplacian operator for 2D functions.

Comment: What is $f$ here?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thanks for the note. Just updated the question. $f$ is a scalar function.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You give us $\psi$ and then we simply define $f$ by the LHS of your identity. Is your question whether this is always well-defined?

Comment: There are issues when the gradient vanishes. For example it is unclear what we should get if $\psi$ is constant or if $\psi(x,y)=(x-1)^2$ what happens for $(1,y)$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of those issues, that's why I said that $|\nabla \psi|$ is a smooth positive function, it is never zero.

My question: can always write $\frac{\nabla^2 \psi}{|\nabla \psi|^2}$ as a scalar function $f$, where $f = f(\psi)$?

Comment: In general, we have that if $g, h$ are scalar functions with common domain and $g$ does never vanish, then $\phi=\frac{h}{g}$ is a scalar function too. This is simply because the fraction of two real numbers is again a real number if the denominator is not zero. Thus, the only real question here is how you define the gradient, respectively the Laplacian on the boundary.